# How to set control to use user-defined control class c# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, controls, richtextbox

I have a richTextBox control on my Windows Forms C# Application.

In order to be able to dynamically add text with different colors, I created a separate class:

```
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{

   public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
   {
       box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
       box.SelectionLength = 0;

       box.SelectionColor = color;
       box.AppendText(text);
       box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
   }

}
```

I tried to implemented the integration by doing the following in my Load function (logBox is the name of my richTextBox control):

```
logBox = new RichTextBox { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Font = new Font("Courier New", 10) };
logBox.AppendText("[" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "]", Color.Blue);
logBox.AppendText("Preparing to fetch Instructions...");
```

This does not seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Comment: Make sure you've imported the namespace your extension method class lives in into your form's code-behind class.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, I simply got rid of:

```
logBox = new RichTextBox { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Font = new Font("Courier New", 10) };
```

and now it works. I was expecting my existing richTextBox, logBox, to populate with text but this was not occurring until now.